# How to blend colour changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two different divs, one with an image and one with a solid colour. How would I blend them so the change isn't noticeable?

HTML:

```
<div class="content1">
<h3 class="text1">Our Latest Album<span class="slash">   /   </span><span class="text2">Fresh from the house of Music Club Band</span></h3>
</div>
<div class="album">
    <div class="album1"><img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA9133-650x385.jpg" alt="album1"></div>
    <div class="album2"><img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA9099-650x385.jpg" alt="album2"></div>
    <div class="album3"><img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA0373-650x385.jpg" alt="album3" class="album4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/album-title.jpg");
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.text1 {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #6CB9D9;
}


.album1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.album1:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.album2{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.album2:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.album3 {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.album3:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.album {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191919;
}

.album img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Because my post is mostly code:
More details
More details
More details
More details
More details
More details

Comment: @A Morris look into `blend-mode` property of CSS

[Nice Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS gradient, configured such that the first part of it is solid and the remainder transitions.

```
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e5799+0,7db9e8+100&1+0,0.7+48,0+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(76,134,191,0.7) 48%, rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(48%,rgba(76,134,191,0.7)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(76,134,191,0.7) 48%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(76,134,191,0.7) 48%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(76,134,191,0.7) 48%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(76,134,191,0.7) 48%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#007db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

There is also CSS blend-mode, but support varies.  http://caniuse.com/#search=blend-mode